# Is Sona a better champion as defensive support or an aggressive one?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is Sona a better defensive support champ or is it plausible to use her in a more aggressive role? I have built her up in bot games for her passive nuke but would that be plausible in pro play?

Answer (score 1):

Sona is a super harasser. In the laning phase she should in the bushes constantly harassing the other support and AD carry and using power cords. While doing this Mana management and positioning are always key

Answer (score 1):

She can fill both roles. Maxing W will help grant you great sustain. Maxing Q will increase your poke by a significant amount. With the recent nerfs to her Auras, Sona has lost of early game power, making her more defensive than agressive.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on  how you play her, if you max q first then you will be a great aggressive support early on, if you want to go defensive go w and you will be able to heal a good amount at a steady pace.

The key is to determine when to go aggressive and when to go defensive. I base it on who I am laning with, if I have a low damage dealer who is going tanky, I tend to go more aggressive to make for the lack of damage, however if I say lane with vayne, she tends to have enough damage and the heals will allow her to poke and dominate the lane.

Sometimes I also go aggressive sided with another heavy damage dealer like kog to shut down the other team completely. If played correctly of course. Try out both ways and see what works best for you!

Answer (score 0):

She's better as a offensive support at the start of games until level 4-5 because she can harass a lot in game. Late game she became more of defensively support but she can still engage a fight with her ult.

Answer (score 0):

Sona is a great support champion when played as one. I personally would not play her for damage as she is too focused on keeping the damage output alive. At best, I would play her aggressively with her great harass but not much more than that. She seems to be a much stronger defensive champion than any other role.

Answer (score 0):

I would say she is an offensive support because of her insane poke damage,heals,and buffs if you put her into a poke combo u can win the fights and your lane very much easy as she is a battle support...